# Can I query a List?

Tags: java

Say I have

```java
    List<SomeObject> objList = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();
```

If SomeObject contains a field named id. Can we find it through some query like

```java
objList.filter('id=2');
```

without looping through the list? If not, then why? This can be such a useful method and can be used as an alternative to write a tedious for loop.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-collection

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846771/how-to-selectively-filter-items-in-a-collection

Comment: Thanks Yuppie. Yours is the most relevant answer.

Comment: You can do objList.select(idEqualTo(2)) when using this library https://github.com/nicholas22/jpropel-light. You have to define the function idEqualTo() but it's a one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something like linq for java, check out [quaere](https://github.com/anoras/Quaere)

---

**Edit:** At this point, quaere looks like it is unmaintained.  With Java 7 being EOL, you should be on Java 8 whose [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) should get you most of the way there when compared to Linq's dot syntax.  See [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) for some examples.

Comment: stylish, eventually slow, contains implicit loop

Answer (score 8):

Libraries with functional, well, functionality such as [functionaljava](http://functionaljava.org/) provide such 
methods.

You'd need to use its own `List` implementation which is incompatible to native Javas `(Array)List` or convert between the two.

An Example:

```
import fj.data.Java
import fj.data.List
import fj.F

// Converting an ArrayList
fj.data.List<SomeObject> objList2 = Java.ArrayList_List().f(objList);

fj.data.List<SomeObject> filteredObjList = objList2.filter(new F<SomeObject, Boolean>() {
  Boolean f(SomeObject c) { return c.id == 2; } 
});

// Converting back to ArrayList
java.util.List<SomeObject> objList2 = Java.List_ArrayList().f(filteredObjList );
```

By using functionaljava's `List` through out of your project you would avoid the converting.

Answer (score 2):

Even if this was a supported feature of the language, then it would be Java that would need to do the iterating, so you're back at square one (in terms on time complexity).

What you're looking for is associative mapping. This can be achieved with HashMap. If you want to associate by more than one type of property for example id AND name, then you could make two HashMaps, one whose key is id and one whose key is name.

This of course doesn't scale very well if you want to query for many properties, so the next step would be using an Object oriented database such as Hibernate which will allow you to query the database for objects exactly as in your example.

Comment: Well, i am not worried about running time. I am more worried about my coding time (my productivity). Just one extra method call is not going to miserably slow down my application. And i don't want to use Hashtable kind of data structure. Actually i want something similar to what Linq offers in .Net where you can directly query a collection

Comment: @Nitesh, Sorry not familiar with .NET. But you cannot query a collection in Java as in your example (there may be some 3rd party frameworks or libraries that do this).

Answer (score 2):

short: no, you can't

long: you can write own data structure and hash/index fields of object for some more efficient search. but this is not a list, more `HashMap` or so.

Answer (score 2):

Probably this will help someone,

http://code.google.com/p/joquery/

this library supports following code structure,

```
Filter<Dto> query = CQ.<Dto>filter(testList)
    .where()
    .property("id").eq().value(1);
Collection<Dto> filtered = query.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here
[How do you query object collections in Java (Criteria/SQL-like)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93417/how-do-you-query-object-collections-in-java-criteria-sql-like)
you can see some nice option/ I've sopped on this one actually.